# Is AutoMapper expected to silently fail when mapping the same type without a map configured?

Tags: automapper

Consider the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

[Test]
void Main()
{
    var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(c => c.AddProfile<EmptyProfile>()).CreateMapper();
    var foo = new Foo(){Bar = 1};
    var baz = new Foo();
    mapper.Map(foo, baz); // does not throw AutoMapperMappingException
    Assert.AreEqual(foo.Bar, baz.Bar); // fails
}
```

Is this expected behavior using 10.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the maintainers, this is by design.

> That's by design. But check
> https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration-validation.html#custom-validations.

from https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3480

Comment: "This is such an edge case, it's not worth the effort is why." This is the rational behind their choice.